# android mapview loading

Tags: android, maps

I am making an android app in which i am using mapviews. they are working perfectly on the device when installed from the pc.but when the same build is installed in device through android market, the maps does not load. following is the logcat output.

```
10-03 15:54:51.784: WARN/System.err(12994): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
10-03 15:54:51.784: WARN/System.err(12994):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
10-03 15:54:51.784: WARN/System.err(12994):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
10-03 15:54:51.784: WARN/System.err(12994):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
10-03 15:54:51.784: WARN/System.err(12994):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
10-03 15:54:51.784: WARN/System.err(12994):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
10-03 15:54:51.784: WARN/System.err(12994):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

what could be the problem 
can anyone please help me over ths??
thanks

Comment: did you create keystore for the device? or you are using key which was created using debug.keystore

Comment: @pratik i am using debug.keystore

Comment: @venky yup i signed app and had followed steps for making mapview

Comment: for device you have to create another keystore and generate new key for the map. this will be for all the device while the debug.keystore was used for the machine specific like virtual device only for debuging

Comment: @Pratik can you p[ls tell me how to generate different keystore for map

Comment: @venky i am not getting ua point  can u pls clear ua qs

Comment: You need to Sign your App using Release Key not using default android's "debug.keystore".. If you use debug.keystore map will not visible for all user so u need to use Release Key to do so..

Comment: as you export create new keystore and save in c/d drive now use this keystore to obtain md5 finger. now after getting new key change it and again export with existing keystore just it

Answer (score 7):

You can't use debug.keystore to create a Google Maps API key for applications going into the market. If you already have the application (or indeed any application) in the market then **you already have the keystore you should use**. This is how you use this keystore to get a Google Maps API key:

Step 1: At the command line navigate to the directory with your keystore file in it:

```
cd <keystore-dir>
```

Step 2: Now list the contents of your keystore:

```
keytool -list -keystore <your-keystore-file>
```

Step 3: Enter the password for your keystore when prompted. Keytool will now display a list of certificates and their MD5s.

Step 4: Copy the MD5 for the certificate you are going to use to sign your application into your copy/paste buffer.

Step 5: Open a browser and navigate to http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html - **if you're not logged in with your Android Market account**, you'll need to do that next, before you generate your API key.

Step 6: Paste the MD5 from your copy/paste buffer into the text box labelled "My certificate's MD5 fingerprint:" and tick the "I have read and agreed..." box.

Step 7: Click 'Generate API Key'. You'll now see the API key you need to use.

Step 8: Copy and paste the API key into your MapView component's `android:apiKey` property.

If you have multiple `MapView` components then you can declare a string resource:

```
<string name="production_api_key">thisIsMyKeyValue</string>
```

Now you can use this in your `android:apiKey` property in the same way that you reference any other string value:

```
android:apiKey="@string/production_api_key"
```

Now export the application to an APK file using the certificate you used in step 4.

Provided you follow this step-by-step guide you should be OK - I've just myself started using a maps API key generated in this way.

Things to watch out for:

- Using the MD5 of the keystore file (`md5 <my-keystore-file>`), not of the certificate. Its the MD5 of the **certificate** you need.
- Being logged in to Google when you generate the API key, but with the wrong account. Your maps API key and your Android Market signing key **must** belong to the same Google account.

Comment: I am experiencing the opposite issue: I cannot get the app to run in debug mode, even though I set up the api key.